# Check inArray dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I have stuck somewhere, may be it's the simplest question but I had tried googling as much as I can and didn't find the exact result.

- I have a simple calendar, added by HTML, jquery
- In my woocomerce/WordPress site, I want to show the booked number of products based on booking start and end date on the calendar. Something like when a user hovers on the dates on the calendar, the number of booked products would show underneath date. (*I am developing a rent website which takes dates range from start to end, just like hotels, this can be ignored*.)
- The calendar is showing fine for one product as shown in image
  [image]

**BUT** if in case say for August 18, we have two products booked, I want to show there "2 booked"

for this, I am using inArray function.

- I have an array of dates (var *only_dates*)
- I have the current dates (var *some*)[inside the range of start and end]

I have tried `console.log(jQuery.inArray(some, only_dates))`

and this is giving me the result 
[image]
As screenshot, we have 18-August already, so in the second time, I want to count it as 2 & then same for 19-August too & so on.

for one object we can try by

```
if(jQuery.inArray(some, only_dates) == 1)
        {
        console.log('found')
        }
```

but in my case, how can I use inArray for dynamically in loop (for more than) and then print the number of occurance.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT:** 
So Here's my code

```
$sepr_date = getDatesFromRange($start, $end); /*a function that coverts range dates into sequence*/
            foreach ($sepr_date as $dt) {?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                ds = {'Date': new Date("<?php echo $dt; ?>"), 'Title': 'Booked', 'Link': 'javascript:void(0)'},
                events_s.push(ds)
                var some = "<?php echo $dt; ?>"
                only_dates.push(some)
                console.log(some)
                console.log(only_dates)
                if(jQuery.inArray(some, only_dates) != -1)
                {
                    console.log('found ' + some)
                }
                </script>   
            <?}?>
```

console giving :

[image]

While pushing item, I wanna check existence.
and if found, increment count. 
If not found, do nothing as simple as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep` function:

```
var count = $.grep(only_dates, function (elem) {
    return elem === some;
}).length;
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5658562/7604006

Comment: Why is this better than `$.inArray`?

Comment: Because it counts the occurrence in array and inArray doesn't.

Comment: Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the built-in `indexOf`, `$.inArray()` returns `-1` when the value isn't found, so you have to compare with that.

```
if (jQuery.inArray(some, only_dates) != -1) {
    console.log('found');
}
```

Comment: Tried, It always giving me 'found'. Not the required result.

Comment: What are the values of `some` and `only_dates`?

Comment: You say above that `only_dates` is an object. `$.inArray` is for searching arrays, not objects.

Comment: only_dates = ["2017, 08, 17", "2017, 08, 18", "2017, 08, 19", "2017, 08, 21", "2017, 08, 22", "2017, 08, 23", "2017, 08, 18", "2017, 08, 19", "2017, 08, 20"]

Comment: And what is the value of `some` when it's giving you `found` but you don't think it should?

Comment: Try changing it to `console.log('found ' + some)` so you see what it's finding.

Comment: Actually, I have an array that pushing range of starting to ending dates, for eg say date 17-19 : "2017, 08, 17", "2017, 08, 18", "2017, 08, 19". Then inside the loop, I want to compare the current date ie say 18 with the only_dates array. If repetition found, I want to increment the count.

Comment: We're going to need to see more code to understand what you're actually doing and why it's not working. These descriptions are not enough.

Comment: `some` will always be found in `only_dates`, because you do `only_dates.push(some)` a few lines before you call `$.inArray()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152128/discussion-between-bilal-hussain-and-barmar).